# sails js layout view change folder

Tags: sails.js

My project has more than one layout, I want to make a folder to contain these layouts and pull them out of the view folder, but when I do this, the layout does not load when I run the application.

How could I solve this?

Tx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you have two options, depending on whether you are using routes or the controller to serve your views.

Firstly, let's say you have a folder "mylayouts" in your views folder and this folder contains numerous layouts eg. "layout_home.ejs", "layout_admin.ejs" etc.

To use these layouts for a specific view, you can:

A. Set the layout using locals in the config/routes.js file, be sure to include both the folder name and layout filename. eg.

```
'/': {
    view: 'homepage',
    locals: {
        layout: '/mylayouts/layout_home.ejs'
    }
}
```

B. Set the layout in the response from the controller, again insuring to include both the folder name and layout filename. eg.

```
/**
 * AdminController
 *
 * @description :: Server-side logic for managing admins
 * @help        :: See http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Controllers
 */

module.exports = {

    index : function(req, res){
        res.view({
            layout : '/mylayouts/layout_admin.ejs'
        })
    }

};
```

Comment: create a route for each view ? i don't think this is a best way to resolve my problem, tx

Comment: Look at option B.

Comment: not work , in my view.js file in the config folder i have layout: 'layout',

  'get /index': {
    view: 'homepage/index',
    locals: {
      layout: 'layout_homepage'
    }
  },

Comment: The view.js file is where you set the default layout. The routes.js file or the specific controller response is where you set the layout for a specific view.

Comment: I have extended my example in option B.